# How to save a dynamic button permanently even when the machine is restarted

Tags: c#

i have made a form with textbox and a save button in visual studio C#, entering text in textbox and clicking save creates a dynamic button on the other form in a vertical flowlayout panel,but when i re-run my application with a new text in the textbox,or restart my application then the previous button is lost, so tell me some logic or code that how can i save that dynamic button permanently in flowlayout panel and when new text is saved it creates  another button below that of previously created one and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For saving something done at the run-time, you either have to use a file, or use the `Application Settings`. A good reference about application settings can be found here on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730869%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

You can create a setting of a type like `ButtonsList` (which you have to write a class for) to store the button created. I said `ButtonsList` considering that you want to save more properties of each button. If you don't need to save anything else but the caption, you can set that property to be a string array.

Also, a very important thing, is that after the `Save` button is clicked, you have to call

```
Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
```

to keep the saved data while your application is not on.

Steps:

1. In Visual Studio, click `PROJECT` menu item.
2. Click `<project-name> Properties` item.
3. In the opened window, go to `Settings` on the left-side pane.
4. Click `Setting` in the table in the middle of the window, and type in the name of the setting that you want to create (e.g `dynamicButtons`).
5. Click on `string` drop-down, and choose `System.Colletions.Specialized.StringCollection`.
6. Go to your program and in the `Save` click event type:

   `Properties.Settings.Default.dynamicButtons.Add("button1_caption");`
   `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();`

Below is the code for a simple collection of `ButtonInfo`s called `ButtonsCollection`:

```
class ButtonInfo
{
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public Point Location { get; set; }
    public Size ButtonSize { get; set; }
    public ButtonInfo(string caption, Point location, Size size )
    {
        this.Caption = caption;
        this.Location = location;
        this.ButtonSize = size;
    }
}

class ButtonsCollection : System.Collections.CollectionBase
{
    public void Add(ButtonInfo bi)
    {
        List.Add(bi);
    }

    public void Remove(int index)
    {
        if (index > Count - 1 || index < 0)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Index not valid!");
        }
        else
        {
            List.RemoveAt(index);
        }
    }

    public ButtonInfo Item(int index)
    {
        return (ButtonInfo)List[index];
    }
}
```

Since the visual designer for Settings in Visual Studio does not allow you to use custom type settings, you will have to do some manual work. You will find more about creating these custom settings [here, on MSDN.](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/52593ade-808b-4614-bb64-4d99b80b3f00/can-i-have-custom-setting-type?forum=csharpgeneral)

Hope my effort is not useless :)

Comment: thank you so much, very informative but along with the text of the button i also want to save its position in the flowlayout panel, so that when next time button generated ,it should be created right below the previous one. so how to do that also..?

Comment: if you consider, please mark my answer as the one for your question :)

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to save the information you need to recreate the button (maybe a label, the position or order) to a configuration file of some form. When you start up the application, check if the file exists. If it does, read it back in and then recreate your buttons.

Comment: can you provide me some link on how to do that??